# php glob not returning all files

Tags: php, load, return, loading, glob

I looked at similar questions here and around the web, but none of the solutions have worked.

I'm using `glob` to return 177 images from a folder. Only some return. Sometimes nothing returns. Every time I reload the page, a few more images are loaded. In the inspector, everything looks like it's loaded; the entire code is how it should be. But looking at the page, I can see that there are obviously images missing.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

    set_time_limit(0);
    ignore_user_abort(1);

    $images = glob("images/pics/*", GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach ($images as $image) { ?>

    <div class='img_container_2 backing_center' style='background: none'>
        <img style='width: 400px' src = '<?php echo $image; ?>'/>
    </div>
<?php

    }

?>
```

I was thinking it might be a time-out problem, but setting the limit to 0 doesn't seem to make a difference. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tested first something simple as `foreach (glob("images/pics/*.png") as $image)`?

Comment: @user2094178 just tried your suggestion. I'm still getting the same problem :/

Comment: This is weird, try `$images = scandir('images/pics/');`

Answer (score 1):

PHP [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function works perfectly in your code.

There is a problem with your directory:

1. Be sure your folder contains **images only**
2. **Remove** `Thumbs.db` in your `$images` array

Remove `Thumbs.db`

```
$key = array_search('Thumbs.db', $images );
$new_images = unset($images[$key]);
```

To Find Images only

```
$images = glob("images/pics/*.jpg", GLOB_BRACE);
```

**Note** : If your folder only contains images, then you don't have to use `.jpg` in `glob` function.

Answer (score 1):

You specify `GLOB_BRACE` as the 2nd argument for glob in order for it to work.

So for example, if you executed `glob("{a,b,c}.php", GLOB_BRACE)` on the following list of files:

```
a.php

b.php

c.php
```

Replace **GLOB_BRACE** with **GLOB_NOSORT** (Return files as they appear in the directory (no sorting). When this flag is not used, the pathnames are sorted alphabetically)

> For more details **[see globe flags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)**

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I did a dumb thing. I set the width to an absolute value when it should have been set to a relative value. I'm still not sure why only some images were showing and some weren't, but at least it's fixed now. Thanks anyway for the help, everyone!